# SQLException when I make a query on a self-referenced entity

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an Entity builded according this pattern :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "participation_formation")
public class ParticipationFormation extends Model {

    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_formation")
    public Formation formation;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_adp")
    public AssistantDePrevention assistantDePrevention;

    @Column(name = "a_participe")
    public boolean aParticipe;

    @Column(name = "commentaire_participation")
    public String commentaireParticipation;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @Column(name = "formation_remplacement")
    public ParticipationFormation formationRemplacement;
}
```

I try to make a query like this :

```
public static List<ParticipationFormation> search(JsonNode node) {
    ExpressionList<ParticipationFormation> query = ParticipationFormation.find.where();
    if (node.has("aParticipe"))
        query.eq("aParticipe", node.get("aParticipe").asBoolean());
    if (node.has("formation"))
        query.eq("formation", Formation.extract(node.get("formation")));
    if (node.has("assistantDePrevention"))
        query.eq("assistantDePrevention", AssistantDePrevention.extract(node.get("assistantDePrevention")));
    return query.findList();
}
```

The `extract()` methods have a special logic for retrieving or creating beans from a Json Node.

In my case, node have only a "assistantDePrevention" field.

When `findList()` is reached, I have this Exception (I shortened the output) :

```
PersistenceException: Query threw new SQLException: Unknown column 't0.formation_remplacement_id' in 'field list'
```

When I remove the cascading informations, it works.

Someone have a solution to my problem, or an explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@Column` to `@JoinColumn` in `formationRemplacement` mapping.